# Accessing Remote JSON file on a server in Firefox

Tags: javascript, json, firefox

I am working on a static local html 5 charting applicaion which fetches data from a remote server and provides the output. The application works fine in google chrome with the below code, however i am not able to make it work on firefox.

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="file://oxtradixtaservdev1/Logs/fragma/frapst3.json"></script>
```

Logs is a shared folder accessible from local, in firefox i am unable to fetch this json file it works fine in chrome. Please assist guys.

Comment: i am not sure but for test can you try with 3 slashes like this `file:///...`

Answer (score 0):

It's possible firefox is blocking calls to the file:// protocol.

Try setting up a webserver on your computer so you can access the file over http instead. This is easy to do, just google how to set up apache for whatever OS you are on